# Replacing first row with values in second row

Tags: sas

My dataset has missing values in the first row of every unique ID. I want to replace this first row with the values in the second row.

My intuition tells me solution involves using `_N_` and `BY`statement.

My Data set:

```
ID  Var1
1   .
1   12
1   23
1   2
2   .
2   266
2   23
2   2
3   .
3   6
```

Result I am after:

```
ID  Var1
1   12
1   12
1   23
1   2
2   266
2   266
2   23
2   2
3   6
3   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two SET statements.  The second SET is for 'lead' processing (as opposed to 'lag').  The data set of the second set statement is the same as the first one but offset by 1 row `(firstobs=2)`.

```
data have;
input ID var1;
datalines;
1   .
1   12
1   23
1   2
2   .
2   266
2   23
2   2
3   .
3   6
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  set have(firstobs=2 keep=id var1 rename=(id=lead1_id var1=lead1_var1));

  if first.id and id=lead1_id then var1=lead1_var1;

  drop lead1_id lead1_var1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: Step1: assigning id wise row number
Step2: Using lag function and replacing second value with the first of each id

```
data have;
input ID  Var1;
cards;
1   .
1   12
1   23
1   2
2   .
2   266
2   23
2   2
3   .
3   6
;
run;

data have1;
set have;
by id;
if first.id then sno = 0;
sno+1;
run;

proc sort data=have1 out=have2;
by id descending sno ;
run;

data have3;
set have2;
var2=lag(var1);
if var1 = . then var1 = var2;
run;

proc sort data=have3 out=want(drop=sno var2);
by id sno;
run;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
data want( rename=(next_var1=var1));
  set have end=eof;
     by id notsorted;
     if first.id then do;
       point = _N_ + 1;
       set have (keep= var1 rename= (var1 = next_var1)) point=point;
    end;
   else do; 
       next_var1=var1;
       end;
     drop var1;
run;
```