# Any clever way to reorganize data set (possibly with lag and output)?

Tags: sas

Can anyone come up with a nice idea to achieve the following in SAS?

We have

```
data test;
input ID $ Score Month_visit;
datalines;
Pat1 10 0
Pat1 9 3
Pat1 3 6
Pat1 7 8
;
```

and I want this test data to be transformed into

```
data final;
input ID $ Score Month;
datalines;
Pat1 10 0
Pat1 10 1
Pat1 10 2
Pat1 9 3
Pat1 9 4
Pat1 9 5
Pat1 3 6
Pat1 7 7
Pat1 7 8
;
```

so basically the score should be printed as often as the difference of (`Month_visit - "change of Month_visit"`) and then just count up.

I have a feeling this could be done with the `lag()`- function and `output statement` but wasn't able do it properly so far. Any ideas?

**Update:**

Actually optimal would be to also cover the process for different `ID`s in the data set:

```
data test;
input ID $ Score Month_visit;
datalines;
Pat1 10 0
Pat1 9 3
Pat1 3 6
Pat1 7 8
Pat2 6 1
Pat2 2 3
Pat2 3 6
Pat2 7 8
;
```

**Solution for the Update:**

If we stick to the solution provided by @draycut, we can simply introduce a `by statement` into the data step, we get:

```
data want (drop=Month_visit:);
    merge test
          test (firstobs=2 keep=Month_visit rename=Month_visit=Month_visit_);
run;

data final;
set want;
by ID;
    if (last.ID NE 1) then do Month = Month_visit to Month_visit_-1;
        output;
    end;
    else do;
        Month = Month_visit;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Why do you need a clever way ? How about straight forward ?

Comment: @Richard that would be ok too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

Also, why is Score=7 in your 8'th obs in final? Shouldn't that be 3?

```
data test;
input ID $ Score Month_visit;
datalines;
Pat1 10 0
Pat1 9 3
Pat1 3 6
Pat1 7 8
;

data want (drop=Month_visit:);
    merge test
          test (firstobs=2 keep=Month_visit rename=Month_visit=Month_visit_);
    if Month_visit_ ne . then do Month = Month_visit to Month_visit_-1;
        output;
    end;
    else do;
        Month = Month_visit;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach works great on the original data set I've posted. I just realized that it would be great to extend this to different ``ID``s as well...I am trying to adapt your approach right now but I see a potential problem with the shifting

Comment: Alright, got it, just introduced the ``by statement`` and it works as expected, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are not reorganizing the data, you are imputing missing values by carrying forward a current value through a monotonic progression sentinel in the next row.

Values from the **next** row are considered **leads**, and a **clever** reuse of the data set, starting from the second row, in a 1:1 merge can provide that.

**Example**

Your `month_visit` values increase, but in the wider problem, suppose there were cases of the values decreasing or missing **and** multiple `ID` groups.

```
data have;
input ID $ Score Month_visit;
datalines;
Pat1 10 0
Pat1 9 3
Pat1 3 6
Pat1 7 8
Pat1 4 4
Pat1 11 0
Pat2 11 0
Pat2 4 4
Pat2 7 . 
Pat2 3 6
Pat2 9 3
Pat2 10 .
;
data want;
  /* 1:1 merge, NO BY STATEMENT */
  merge
    have
    have (firstobs=2 keep=id month_visit rename=(month_visit=lead_month id=lead_id))
  ;

  array step[-1:1] _temporary_ (-1,1,1); /* clever mapping for SIGN() result */

  if lead_id = id and not missing(lead_month) and not missing(month_visit) then
  do month_visit = month_visit 
       to lead_month - step[sign(lead_month - month_visit)]
       by              step[sign(lead_month - month_visit)]
  ;
    output;
  end;
  else 
    output;
run;
```

Also see similar question [Replacing first row with values in second row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849529/replacing-first-row-with-values-in-second-row/49854915#49854915) where lead value is used for imputation.

Comment: I see, you were really serious about the _clever way_, thanks so much! I'll check it out, looks very interesting!

Comment: You're right, _reorganize_ might be a wrong title. Your wider problem is exactly what also came to my mind and which lead to an update of my question. In practice, we will most likely drop missing values like the ones in your test sample and then just sort by the month of visit grouped by the Patient ID.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider a method that does not rely on visits being integers.

```
data test;
   input ID $ Score Visit :$10.;
   datalines;
Pat1 10 Baseline
Pat1 9  V-3
Pat1 3  V-6
Pat1 7  V-EOT
Pat2 6  V-1
Pat2 2  V-3
Pat2 3  V-6
Pat2 7  V-EOT
;;;;
proc print;
   run;
data schedule;
   input Visit :$10.;
   cards;
Baseline
V-1
V-2
V-3
V-4
V-5
V-6
V-EOT
;;;;
   run;
proc summary data=test classdata=schedule nway ORDER=DATA;
   by id;
   class visit;
   output out=want0(drop=_:) idgroup(out(score)=);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   update want0(obs=0) want0;
   by id;
   output;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, that's actually really something I haven't thought about. Great extension to the original problem!